# WebView Alternative for React Native Web Expo

Tags: react-native, webview, expo

I want to display an external website within my app.
Exactly as WebView for Android/iOS.

Expo's React Native WebView does not support the web platform. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webview/

Is there an Expo-friendly alternative for displaying an external website from a url in the web platform?

Comment: could you share what you are expecting to get?

Answer (score 9):

This question needs more details but,

You can platform check and on `Platform.OS === 'web'` use a styled iframe to show external website.

**Update:**

You still didn't say what are you rendering in webview. So I'm just giving you the basic code. You need to do styling for presentation.

**Component:**

```js
//native-webview.tsx
import React, { CSSProperties } from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

interface NativeWebViewProps {
    target: string;
}

export const NativeWebView = (props: NativeWebViewProps): JSX.Element => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
        return <iframe src={props.target} style={styles} />;
    }
    return <WebView source={{ uri: props.target }} />;
};

const styles: CSSProperties = {
    height: 600,
    width: 800
};
```

Usage in `App.tsx`:

```js
// App.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { NativeWebView } from './src/components/native-webview';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <NativeWebView target="https://en.m.wikipedia.org" />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Fixed wrong import.

Comment: How can one add an iframe component to a react native web expo? I have looked into the iframe solution earlier but not found relevant solutions that do not use WebView. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @BernardvanTonder I've updated my answer. The html iframe can be used in expo. See if this approach works for you.

Comment: This approach totally works. This is what we do for our implementation.

Comment: Holy damn. This is wonderful!! MANY thanks!